# Is the infinity product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1+a^k}{1+a^{k+x}}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, closed-form, infinity, products

Let $a$ be a real number belong to $(0,1)$ and consider the following infinity product
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1+a^k}{1+a^{k+x}}$$
Is the  above product convergent( for which x)?
does it have a closed form?

Comment: Well it definitely converges if $x>0$ and $a>0$, since you're just multiplying factors all in $(0,1)$

Comment: and if it converges for $x\in]-1,0[$ then it converges for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @vrugtehagel That is not sufficient to gurantee the convergenmce of an ifinite product. For instace, a necessary condition (which is satisfied in his case) is that the factorsconvrge to $1$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre it is sufficient. To see this, take for example $$\frac11\frac12\frac13\frac14\cdots=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k=0$$ More formally, if $a_n=f(n)a_{n-1}$ and $a_1>0$, where $f:\Bbb N\to(0,1)$, then $(a_n)$ is a strictly decreasing sequence and bounded below by $0$, thus convergent

Comment: @vrugtehagel Infinite products such that the sequence of partial products converges to $0$ are said to be divergent products.

Comment: @Did that's very interesting and good to know. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: For every real number $x$, $$A(x)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+a^{k+x})$$ is a convergent product (this means that the sequence of its partial products converges to a finite nonzero limit) because the positive series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^{k+x}$$ converges, hence the infinite product in the question is always convergent, and its limit is $$B(x)=\frac{A(0)}{A(x)}$$ Obviously, for every nonnegative integer $n$, $$B(n)=\prod_{k=1}^n(1+a^k)$$ and a similar formula exists for $B(-n)$ but, for general values of $x$, I doubt that an explicit formula exists.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments someone said that the product converges for $x>0$ so, for $x<0$, put $y=x-[x]+1>0$.
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1+a^{k}}{1+a^{k+x}}=$$
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{-[x]+1}\frac{1}{1+a^{k+x}}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n+[x]-1}\frac{1+a^{k}}{1+a^{y+k}}\cdot\prod_{k=n+[x]}^{n}(1+a^{k}) $$
Since $a\in(0,1)$, the product converges.

Comment: $[x]$ is the floor function